# AAA Authorization on IOS

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, aaa, tacacs, authorization

Still working away on a project (not for real life deployment so don't worry about seeing passwords).

I have a Tacacs server set up for centralised AAA. I am trying to set up two users, "admin" with full administrative access and "basic" with limited command access. This works perfectly for my ASA firewall however I also want to enable this on an IOS based router.

This works on the router as far as logging in as the users and prompts correctly for a password for enable. However when I try to use commands when logged in as "basic" which should be forbidden they are permitted. From a Wireshark trace I can see that the router is not attempting to contact the tacacs server for authorization of commands. What do I need to add/change to make the router look to the server for command authorization?

Router Config:

```
!
! Last configuration change at 20:03:48 GMT Mon Nov 29 2021 by basic
!
version 15.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname HQ
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local
aaa authentication login HQTACACS group tacacs+ local
aaa authentication enable default group tacacs+ enable
aaa authorization commands 1 default group tacacs+ 
aaa authorization commands 15 default group tacacs+ 
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
clock timezone GMT 0 0
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!


!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
username localadmin privilege 15 secret 5 $1$mX0o$aBpVy.ik5ak8ev4wq9IRf1
!
redundancy
!
!
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 no shutdown
 description TO THE ISP-HQ NETWORK 209.165.200.224/30
 ip address 209.165.200.226 255.255.255.224
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 no shutdown
 description TO THE HQ NETWORK 192.168.10.0/24
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 no shutdown
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 no shutdown
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.252 Ethernet0/0
ip route 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0 Ethernet0/0
ip route 192.31.7.32 255.255.255.224 Ethernet0/0
ip route 192.168.10.10 255.255.255.255 192.168.20.2
ip route 198.133.219.0 255.255.255.252 Ethernet0/0
ip route 209.165.200.227 255.255.255.255 192.168.20.2
ip route 209.165.200.228 255.255.255.255 192.168.20.2
!
!
!
tacacs-server directed-request
tacacs server HQTACACS
 address ipv4 192.168.10.10
 key testing123
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 transport input none
!
!
end
```

Tacacs Server Config:

```
# Created by Henry-Nicolas Tourneur(henry.nicolas@tourneur.be)
# See man(5) tac_plus.conf for more details
 
# Define where to log accounting data, this is the default.
 
accounting file = /var/log/tac_plus.acct
 
# This is the key that clients have to use to access Tacacs+
 
key = testing123
 
# Use /etc/passwd file to do authentication
 
#default authentication = file /etc/passwd
 
 
# You can use feature like per host key with different enable passwords
#host = 127.0.0.1 {
#        key = test 
#        type = cisco
#        enable = <des|cleartext> enablepass
#        prompt = "Welcome XXX ISP Access Router \n\nUsername:"
#}
 
# We also can define local users and specify a file where data is stored.
# That file may be filled using tac_pwd
#user = test1 {
#    name = "Test User"
#    member = staff
#    login = file /etc/tacacs/tacacs_passwords
#}
 
# We can also specify rules valid per group of users.
#group = group1 {
#   cmd = conf {
#       deny
#   }
#}
 
# Another example : forbid configure command for some hosts
# for a define range of clients
#group = group1 {
#   login = PAM
#   service = ppp
#   protocol = ip {
#       addr = 10.10.0.0/24
#   }
#   cmd = conf {
#       deny .*
#   }
#}
 
user = admin {
    default service = permit
    member = admingroup
    login = cleartext Cisco
    enable = cleartext Cisco
}
 
user = basic {
    login = cleartext Cisco
    member = readonly
    enable = cleartext Cisco
}
 
group = admingroup {
    default service = permit
    service = exec {
        priv-lvl = 15
    }
}
 
group = readonly {
    default service = deny
    service = exec {
        priv-lvl = 0
    }
 
 
    cmd = show {
        permit .*
    }
 
    cmd = traceroute {
        permit .*
    }
 
    cmd = ping {
        permit .*
    }
 
    cmd = exit {
        permit .*
    }
}
 
# Much more features are availables, like ACL, more service compatibilities,
# commands authorization, scripting authorization.
# See the man page for those features.
```

Edited Config as per answer now contains lines:

```
aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local
aaa authentication login HQTACACS group tacacs+ local
aaa authentication enable default group tacacs+ enable
aaa authorization commands 1 HQTACACS group tacacs+ 
aaa authorization commands 15 HQTACACS group tacacs+
```

But still gives the same behaviour?

Update 2:

I don't have a server group defined, HQTACACS is the server name. The line in the config using it that way looks like a mistake by me. Login authentication and enable mode authentication work with this structure

```
aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local
aaa authentication enable default group tacacs+ enable
```

However when I use the same structure (with the correction to use level 0 not 1, thanks Ricky) I can see with wireshark that using either the priv level 15 "admin" and priv level 0 "basic" account that not authrization is being attempted.

```
aaa authorization commands 0 default group tacacs+
aaa authorization commands 15 default group tacacs+
```

Do I need a server group defined to use Tacacs for authorization?

Comment: "debug aaa" to see what's being sent for those logins. If the user is priv "0", you've not defined a command group for them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on priv level 0. "debug aaa" doesnt seem to be accepted as a command? I've been using wireshark to see if requests are sent to the server or not.

Comment: "debug aaa ?" will show the slew of options for what to watch. You'll also need the console or syslog logging setup to show debug messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited:**

You use the group tacacs+ for your authentication, but you have not configured a server group for that.  Here is a corrected configuration:

```
aaa authentication login default group HQTACACS local
aaa authentication enable default group HQTACACS enable
aaa authorization commands 0 default group HQTACACS if-authenticated
aaa authorization commands 15 default group HQTACACS if-authenticated
```

additional:

```
aaa group server tacacs+ HQTACACS
 server name HQTACACS
```

Update 2:

If connected via the console (not vty), you need this additional line:

```
aaa authorization console
```

Comment: Thank you, I've changed the authorization lines to use the HQTACACS group but I am still seeing the same behaviour?

Comment: "default" is the correct word. You aren't associating the "HQTACACS" policy to anything.

Comment: @DavidM  Revised the configuration.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm still not getting this right for some reason. I've edited the question again as I don't actually have a server group defined, where I'v used HQTACACS that way it was a mistake.

Comment: @DavidM  See additional commands

Comment: Thanks but still no joy. Using your updated config lines and the server group I can still run high level commands as "basic" (priv level 0) and I see no attempts to authorize coming from the router on wireshark (I do see authentication traffic when logging in)

Comment: You say non-privileged user can run all commands?  That points to a different problem.  Does it persist if you turn off aaa?

Comment: You might be right here. I have two local users created "localbasic" with priv 0 and "localadmin" with priv 15. I've killed the tacacs server and logged in locally and right enough I can run "hostname newname" for example as "localbasic" which I presume I shouldn't be able to?

Comment: Doing a bit more digging when I use "show privilege" as "localbasic" is shows level 15 when it should be 0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131918/discussion-between-ron-trunk-and-davidm).